# Ports with ships in the commercial Halifax trade, late 18th Century

Tags: british-empire, 18th-century, trade, colonial-america, ships

[Halifax, Nova Scotia, was founded by the British in 1749](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Halifax_(former_city)); I am interested in the commercial trade during the [French Revolutionary Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Revolutionary_Wars), 1792 thru 1798, which is the [period of the First Coalition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Revolutionary_Wars#War_of_the_First_Coalition).

[image: British trade routes as shown by ship logs between 1750 and 1800.]

The source of the map is James Cheshire at *Spatial Analysis*, who took the log data from the CLIWOC project database. The database itself is no longer accessible. But see [here](http://projects.knmi.nl/cliwoc/download/cliwoc15.htm). I was able to track down a copy of the database, but it requires MS Access 2000 to read the data, and I have not been able to find a tool to convert the data to the more recent MS Access format.

Map shows British trade routes as derived from ship's logs between 1750 and 1800.

I am interested in learning which ports, American and British, were active in the shipping trade, both to and from Halifax, during this time period.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are referring to as "*this shipping trade*". Are you looking for ports with regular export / import to Halifax, NS? That seems the only possible meaning, but your choice of wording makes even that unclear.

Comment: The source of the map is James Cheshire at [Spatial Analysis](http://spatial.ly/2012/03/mapped-british-shipping-1750-1800/), who took the log data from the [CLIWOC project database](http://webs.ucm.es/info/cliwoc/cliwoc15.htm). The database itself is no longer accessible on that site but you might be able to track it down somewhere on the internet. That data should give you a good indication of what you want to know.

Comment: Modern versions of MS Access should still be able to open a Access .mdb format database.

Comment: @SteveBird: Not so; a major change was made in the file formats when they switched from .mdb to .accdb. Microsoft says "To work around this issue, use a pre-Access 2013 version of Access to save the Access 97 database as an .accdb file: ".  Unfortunately, I don't keep older versions, nor are they available from MS.

Comment: @SteveBird: I take "*Not so; a major change was made in the file formats when they switched from .mdb to .accdb*" as a challenge - however the link appears to be broken for the file ***CLIWOC15_2000.zip***. I'm willing to make a modest effort at retrieval if someone can supply me with the zip file. I so have an **Access 2010 DVD**; and other programming tools in my kit should be able to read the database files also.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens the link at http://projects.knmi.nl/cliwoc/download/cliwoc15.htm seems to work.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: Interesting - it is working again now. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Are CLIWOC entries representative of merchant  shipping voyages? Pieter Geerkens's answer shows only warships visiting Halifax, for instance, and the input data to the CLIWOC project seems to have a built-in selection bias.

Comment: The [Access Database Engine has always been a free, redistributable, download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). What you pay for is the design tools associated with it. Any database-aware application, such as Excel or MS-SQL, can read MDB and ACCDB files once the appropriate vintage of the JET Engine has been installed. There are [32/64-bit issues to be aware of](https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/) however.

Answer (score 1):

I have now downloaded the **CLIWOC15_2000.zip** file, unzipped it to **CLIWOC15_2000.mdb**, and successfully opened it with **MS-ACCESS 2016** by holding ***SHIFT*** down while doing so (This disables any startup macros.) I then declined the option of enabling active content.

The following query

```
SELECT
    ShipName,
    ShipType,
    VoyageIni,
    VoyageFrom,
    VoyageTo,
    Company,
    Nationality,
    Name1, Rank1,
    Name2, Rank2
   ,count(*) as Records
FROM CLIWOC15
WHERE ( VoyageFrom Like "HALIFAX*"
     OR VoyageTo   Like "HALIFAX*"
      )
  AND  Year BETWEEN 1792 and 1798
GROUP BY
    ShipName,
    ShipType,
    VoyageIni,
    VoyageFrom,
    VoyageTo,
    Company,
    Nationality,
    Name1, Rank1,
    Name2, Rank2
ORDER BY
    ShipName,
    ShipType,
    VoyageIni
;
```

(where *Year* is that of the *log entry*) then returns these five Royal Navy voyages:

[image]

Comment: Changing ( CLIWOC15.VoyageFrom Like "HALIFAX*"
     OR CLIWOC15.VoyageTo   Like "HALIFAX*"
      ) to ( CLIWOC15.VoyageFrom Like "\*HALIFAX\*"
     OR CLIWOC15.VoyageTo   Like "\*HALIFAX\*"
      ) made no difference to the results.

Comment: This is a fantastic hands-on approach, and about historical data. But I wonder whether all this is not really better placed at SuperUser? // Please add the links to your source files./ To *really* make me happy this needs an *alternative* to MSAccess, which eg I do not have. +

Comment: @LangLangC: The OLEDB Provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" is available [for 64-bit environments](https://www.connectionstrings.com/using-jet-in-64-bit-environments/) through the [redistributable (free) fownload of the MS_Access database engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255). This should allow one to query the MDB data through another application such as EXCEL or SQL Server.

Comment: @LangLangC: Other issues with OFFICE 32/64-bit compatibility are addressed [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991643/microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine).

Comment: @LangLangC: ***NB***: the Access Database Engine **has always been free** - what you pay for is the suite of design tools. Once the Access Database Engine Redistributable has been installed, any database-aware software (even EXCEL, though performance will be a pig because EXCEL is NOT a database engine) can read ACCDB and MDB files using it as the *provider*. Also any Access application built using the design suite ***can be run locally***.

Comment: Given the sources for the British logbook information (i.e. the NMM Admiralty archives) it's not all that surprising that these are just RN voyages. I'm guessing that the merchant logbooks generally didn't survive beyond the demise of the operating companies (if that long) and, very possibly, didn't contain the detailed weather information that the CLIWOC project was primarily interested in.

Comment: @SteveBird: There are a lot of Spanish entries, but not until later. The archive is primarily for climate and weather research, so records *log entries* by ship captains and other officers. That list of 5 voyages comprises over 150 *log entries*, as noted in the **Records** column. Also Halifax seems to have only [become a Royal Navy station in 1794](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Halifax_(former_city)#Prince_Edward,_Duke_of_Kent_and_Strathearn).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, Looking at the Spanish logs, those too appear to be from naval vessels rather than merchant ships. I suspect that the legend on the map ("British Trade Routes") is somewhat inaccurate. Also Halifax served as a Royal Naval Dockyard, and the headquarters for the Royal Navy's North American Station, from [1759](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Naval_Dockyard,_Halifax).